# What's the attack for Fettering Aegis, if any?

Tags: dnd-4e

It's a Swordmage power. It has a Hit entry but no Attack entry in my character builder.

I noticed at least one other power that has this problem: Master Dimensional Cleave. Both powers are from Dragon Magazine 405.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: Attack Rolls for each power]

Here they are, according to pages 39 and 40 of Dragon Magazine #405